# Function woocommerce for single product copy and set "value" attibute in brand

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I created this woocommerce function that I inserted into the theme's functions.php file. I want to take the term "value" referring to the "name" of a specific attribute of a single product and insert it as the brand term of that product ID.

The following code doesn't work, it doesn't perform the intended function. How to do? Thank you

```
 // Check if the product is a WooCommerce product
 if (get_post_type($product_id) !== 'product') {
     return;
 }

 
 $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

 
 if (!$product->has_attributes()) {
     return;
 }

 
 $attributes = $product->get_attributes();

 
 foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
     if ($attribute->get_name() === 'Manufacturer') {
         
         $brand_value = $product->get_attribute('Manufacturer');

         
         if (!empty($brand_value)) {
             // Copy the value into a taxonomy called 'store'
             wp_set_object_terms($product_id, sanitize_text_field($brand_value), 'store', true);
         }
         return;
     }
 }
}

add_action('woocommerce_update_product', 'copy_brand_value_in_taxonomy');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function copy_brand_value_in_taxonomy($product_id) {
    if (get_post_type($product_id) !== 'product') {
        return;
    }

    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

    if (!$product->has_attributes()) {
        return;
    }

    $attributes = $product->get_attributes();

    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        if ($attribute->get_name() === 'pa_manufacturer') { 
            $brand_value = $product->get_attribute('pa_manufacturer');

            if (!empty($brand_value)) {
                wp_set_object_terms($product_id, sanitize_text_field($brand_value), 'store', false);
            }
        }
    }
}

add_action('save_post', 'copy_brand_value_in_taxonomy', 10, 1);
```